# Heisenberg uncertainty principle in single slit diffraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I have a question about the vertical uncertainty (z direction in the diagram below) for an electron in a single slit diffraction experiment.

[image: Single slit diffraction]

Would it be correct to take the uncertainty to be $3\mu m$, half of the slit width?

Thanks

Comment: Are you treating the slit as a Gaussian source?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have some info on the momentum of the electrons $p$. Using the uncertainty principle we can write
$$
\Delta z=L\Delta \theta=L\frac{\Delta p_z}{p}\approx L\frac{\hbar}{2d\cdot p}
$$
So if we know $p$ we can calculate $\Delta z$

Comment: For the question I'm answering though, I'm trying to calculate the uncertainty in z direction momentum of the electrons, but I don't know the uncertainty in z direction position either, which is why I'm wondering if taking the approximation of half the slit width would be correct and if so why or why not? Thanks for the reply

Comment: The $\Delta z$ in my answer is the spread of electrons at the distance $L$. The uncertainty at the  screen is best approximated by the slit width. For sure the electrons are confined to this width when they pass the slit. I don't see a good reason to take half of that width as the uncertainity.